# How do i allow user to login with username or email

Tags: wordpress, function

I would like to allow users to login and access a page with username or email address. I have written a function that allow user to login with email address without the password field. I want users to be able to use both username and email to access the page without the password field.

```
 //Function to hide password field
function admin_login( $user, $email, $password) {
   $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
    if($user != "FALSE")
    {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

    return $user;
}


function hide_password_field() 
{
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body.login div#login form#loginform p:nth-child(2) {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}

add_filter("authenticate", "admin_login", 10, 3);
add_action("login_head", "hide_password_field");
```

With the codes above, Users are able to login with email address without password. How do i make users login with both username or email without password.

Comment: $user = get_user_by('login','loginname');

Comment: The system triggered password field is required. However, I want to login with either email or username without password filed. The code above allow me to login with email address without password. I want to be able to login with both email and username without password field